# Saving data in a cell in the next empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I have code which sends a file via Outlook and gets-saves data into an Excel file.

For sending a file via Outlook, it works perfectly. However it saves data into the same row of the Excel file. Code should save data into the next empty row of the Excel file.

```
Sub AutoEmail()
    On Error GoTo Cancel
    Dim Resp As Integer
    Resp = MsgBox(prompt:=vbCr & "Yes = Review Email" & vbCr & "No = Immediately Send" & vbCr & "Cancel = Cancel" & vbCr, _
    Title:="Review email before sending?", _
    Buttons:=3 + 32)
    'dfsfsd

    Range("S20").Copy
    Range("T20").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'sdaasdf

    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\computername\Desktop\New folder (2)\ff.xlsx")
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    '1
    Workbooks("1435250.xlsx").Worksheets("RFI").Range("T20").Copy _
        Workbooks("ff.xlsx").Worksheets("Sayfa1").Range("P2")
    '1
    Select Case Resp

        'Yes was clicked, user wants to review email first
        Case Is = 6
            Dim myOutlook As Object
            Dim myMailItem As Object

            Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set otlNewMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            FName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

            With otlNewMail
            .To = Cells(33, 10)
            .CC = Cells(1, 1)
            .Subject = Cells(23, 10) & ": " & Cells(21, 10)
            .Body = "this is a text" & vbCr & vbCr & "" & Cells(23, 10) & "."
            .Attachments.Add FName
            .Display

            End With


            Set otlNewMail = Nothing
            Set otlApp = Nothing
            Set otlAttach = Nothing
            Set otlMess = Nothing
            Set otlNSpace = Nothing


        'If no is clicked
        Case Is = 7
            Dim myOutlok As Object
            Dim myMailItm As Object

            Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set otlNewMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            FName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

            With otlNewMail
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .Subject = ""
            .Body = "Good Morning," & vbCr & vbCr & " " & Format(Date, "MM/DD") & "."
            .Attachments.Add FName
            .Send
            '.Display
            'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            'Application.SendKeys "%s"

            End With

            'otlApp.Quit

            Set otlNewMail = Nothing
            Set otlApp = Nothing
            Set otlAttach = Nothing
            Set otlMess = Nothing
            Set otlNSpace = Nothing
        'If Cancel is clicked
        Case Is = 2
Cancel:
            MsgBox prompt:="No Email has been sent.", _
            Title:="EMAIL CANCELLED", _
            Buttons:=64

    End Select

End Sub
```

How can I save data (End(xlUp).Row) into the next empty row of an Excel file?

Comment: To clarify: your code is copying `T20` from `1435250.xlsx` into `T20` in `ff.xlsx` but you want it to copy to `P2` in `ff.xlsx`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!
no mate, code is copying T20 from 1435250.xlsx into P2 in ff.xlsx. the thing i want is code should be aware of cells are empy or not. if P2 is not empty, code should save it into P3 in ff.xlsx. it should continue like that.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Workbooks("1435250.xlsx").Worksheets("RFI").Range("T20").Copy _
    Workbooks("ff.xlsx").Worksheets("Sayfa1").Range("P2")
```

To this:

```
With Workbooks("ff.xlsx").Worksheets("Sayfa1")
    Workbooks("1435250.xlsx").Worksheets("RFI").Range("T20").Copy .Range("P" & .Range("P" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
End With
```

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer